# Bootstrap 3 change <ul> height inside row

Tags: css, list, twitter-bootstrap-3

Inside row, I have list, and each `<li>` tag has set left and right border.

```
<div class="container>
<div class="row>
      <ul class="list">
        <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
      </ul>
</div>
</div>

<style>
ul.list > li {
border-right:1px solid #eeeeee;
border-left:1px solid #eeeeee;
}
</style>
```

[image]

Now, I need to set ul.test height to 100% inside row, to remove padding-top and padding-bottom from row, then borders for `<li>` tags will stay from top to bottom of row.

I tried a couple ideas with row padding, with list height but no success

Comment: May i know  what type of requirement  you have?send the picture if any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [bootstrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) you need to have `.col-*-*` as a direct child of `.row`

Then you need to remove bootstrap default `margin-bottom` of `ul` and `padding-left/right` from `.col-*-*`

```css
.row {
  background: red
}
.container ul {
  background: lightgreen;
  margin-bottom: 0
}
.container li {
  border: solid #eee;
  border-width: 0 1px;
  display: inline-block;
  /* demo */
  padding:0 5px;
  margin:0 5px
}

.container div[class^="col-"] {
  padding: 0
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <ul class="list">
        <li><a href="#">1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">2</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">3</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">4</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hi,tnx for time, of course, I just forget to put div with column class, but anyway, I try to make borders with full height,so no space between top an bottom of <li>

Comment: @pavlenko have you checked my fiddle? there is no space between borders. and column or row.